# Regex to match words with punctuation but not punctuation alone

Tags: regex, swift

I need to match words from a string that potentially have symbols, both in a word also as a punctuation. An example string could be:

```
This string's is a good example of situation I'll fail to match - due to punctuations being all over the place.
```

Ignoring the weird English of that sentence, I have a case where I need to match every word but not punctuation unless it is part of the word. So my result should be

1. This
2. string's (match `'s` since it is part of the word)
3. is
4. a
5. good

...

9. I'll (match the `'ll` to I since it is part of the word)
10. fail
11. to
12. match
13. due (skip the `-`)
14. to

...

18. the
19. place (no full stop since it is not part of the word.)

I manage to come up with two regex that works partially but neither works the way I want

```
(?<=\\s|^)[A-Za-z0-9]+?(?=\\s|$) - I am using swift so `\\s` is for whitespace
```

This matches normal words but not cases like `string's` since there is a `'` in the word. But if I use my other expression:

```
(?<=\\s|^).+?(?=\\s|$)
```

It matches `string's` but also `-` and the full stop at the end of sentences like `place.`

Is there an expression that matches words with punctuation but not punctuation alone? I do not mind if it requires multiple expression to capture all the results, I can merge the result before displaying.

Note: Apart from the example given, punctuations that I know could both exist as part of a word or not includes `-` `'` `()` `.` whereas punctuation that will only be part of a word includes `%` `$` `#` `&` `/` any other punctuation can be assumed to never be part of any word. `!` `?` `"` `:` are expected to appear with or without spacing from words but must not be matched into the result.

Fortunately, the string can be safely assume to only contain alphanumerics and punctuation symbols - other language characters and symbols like `<>{}[]|` or `+*=` can be assumed to not appear in the string - there are some other symbol that fits into one of the four groups of symbol that I cannot predict now but I believe if I can get a logic that works I can adapt it to include more symbols in each group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need a regex that will be able to match selected symbols that are either preceded or followed with "word" characters, or just letters/digits or parentheses letters/digits. All that should be either inside whitespaces, start/end of string positions, or word boundaries (note this order is important).

Use

```
(?<=\\s|^|\\b)(?:[-'.%$#&/]\\b|\\b[-'.%$#&/]|[A-Za-z0-9]|\\([A-Za-z0-9]+\\))+(?=\\s|$|\\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpOqXy/3).

**Details**:

- `(?<=\\s|^|\\b)` - a positive lookbehind requiring that there must be whitespace, or start of string or a word boundary to the left of the current location
- `(?:`  - start of the non-capturing group, matching 1+ sequences of:

  - `[-'.%$#&/]\\b` - the specified symbols followed with a word char
  - `|` - or
  - `\\b[-'.%$#&/]` - the specified symbols preceded with a word char
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]` - an alphanumeric
  - `|` - or
  - `\\([A-Za-z0-9]+\\)` - a `(`, followed with 1+ alphanumeric symbols, and a `)`
- `)+` - end of the non-capturing group
- `(?=\\s|$|\\b)` - a positive lookahead requiring that there must be a whitespace, end of string or a word boundary immediately to the right of the current location.

To only match dots as decimal separators, add an additional `\d*\.?\d+` branch and take out `.` from the character classes:

```
(?<=\\s|^|\\b)(?:[-'%$#&/]\\b|\\b[-'%$#&/]|\\d*\\.?\\d+|[A-Za-z0-9]|\\([A-Za-z0-9]+\\))+(?=\\s|$|\\b)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpOqXy/6)

Comment: I wanted to edit the answer directly but it says need to at least change 6 characters. If you remove `.` from `\\b[-'.%$#&/]` the full stop at end of sentences will not be matched, slightly more accurate to what I need. Making the full expression `(?<=\\s|^|\\b)(?:[-'.%$#&/]\\b|\\b[-'%$#&/]|[A-Za-z0-9]|\\([A-Za-z0-9]+\\))+(?=\\s|$|\\b)`. I will update as I manage to improve it further.

Comment: Ok, judging by your previous comments, you only need to match a dot if it is a decimal separator. Then use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/IpOqXy/6). Note however, the dot won't be matched in abbreviations like `Dr.`, either. You would have to list all abbreviations with dot in an additional branch then.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a maximum of one punctuation symbols in a word, you can try :

```
(?<=\\s|^) ([A-Za-z0-9]+? | [A-Za-z0-9]*?[\-\'\(\)\.\%\$\#\&\/][A-Za-z0-9]*? ) (?=\\s|$)
```

But  Wiktor Stribiżew  solution is better :

```
(?<=\\s|^|\\b)(?:[-'.%$#&/]\\b|\\b[-'.%$#&/]|[A-Za-z0-9]|\\(‌​[A-Za-z0-9]+\\))+(?=‌​\\s|$|\\b)
```

Comment: I am sorry, that assumption is not true. Your answer got me further but there are words like `apple(s)` which both brackets must be matched and `(else?)` where only `else` is matched. Also numbers like `$13.30` are to be matched as one word. Trickiest regex I ever faced.

Comment: and have you try the second one ?

Comment: I removed that one (`(?<=\\s|^)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\-\'\(\)\.\%\$\#\&\/][A-Za-z0-9]+)*(?=\\s|$)`), it does not work for the cases in the comment above. BTW, your overescaping does not look nice. All of those symbols are not special chars inside character classes and the `-` is not special at the beginning of a character class.

Comment: edited ! yep the first one don't match if the word start with punctuation symbol

Comment: I overescape to avoid fail of auto color

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks. This answer is almost complete, I tested it against all extreme inputs I expect to received and all matched correctly! I couldn't come up with half of the expression by myself. Edit - except full stop at end of sentences but I expected that since I needed to match decimal digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, if you could post a formal answer with explanation of the expression I'd make that the accepted answer of course! But no worries, I can understand your expression alright, just couldn't come up with it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

if the punctuation always follow without word something like **coma then space** or **dash then space**, can you just use this regex `\W{2,}` ?

note : 
\W matches any non-word character (equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])
{2,} Quantifier — Matches between 2 and unlimited times

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I am trying to match words with or without symbol(s), not the symbols themselves.

Comment: Ah, Im sorry for that, but if you want that you need rule of what you define as punctuation first. for example your accepted answer will still not match if you add something like "this 50% discount" since it have same pattern to "match match, due", because the requirement is always growing.(but your new accepted answer can :D)

Comment: Good catch! But as you can see, the expression in the answer is already very complex and it is sufficient to cover most common occurrences. I do believe from here on it is fair enough I work on it to cover the remaining exceptions myself. I do appreciate your help in catching the misses of that expression.